# How to modify Centos 5.5 default open command

Tags: file, types, centos, associations

In Centos 5.5, each time I double click a file named "*.pl" in File Browser, it open a new emacs editor instance.

I want Emacs to run in a single instance way, so I need to modify the open command to "emacsclient %f", but I don't know where and how to modify the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is:

```
1. Find a .pl file on your desktop or in the File Browser (nautilus)
2. Right click it, select Properties
3. Pick "Open With" tab
4. If you don't see emacsclient, press the add button
   a. Can check the list in Add Application dialog for emacsclient
      I) If absent, click Use a custom command and browse or enter the path
         to the emacsclient executable (mine is at /usr/local/bin/emacsclient).
   b. Select emacsclient in the list
   c. Press the Add button
5. Make sure the radiobutton is selected for emacsclient in the "Open With"
   dialog
6. Press the close button.
```